# Am I able to to use a string variable for a file name with fstream? C++

Tags: c++

I want to be able to take text input and store it in a string variable like so:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    string fileInput = "filetoinput.txt";
    ifstream inputFile (fileInput);
}
```

But it will only accept creating an ifstream type variable like so:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile ("filetoinput.txt");
}
```

Is there a way to make a string variable act like text in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `.c_str()` method:

```
ifstream inputFile (fileInput.c_str());
```

Answer (score 4):

With C++11 the original example should work:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::string fileInput = "filetoinput.txt";
std::ifstream inputFile(fileInput);
```

If you're not up to C++11, then `fileInput.c_str()` gives you a C-style string that you can use for the call:

```
std::ifstream inputFile(fileInput.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile (fileInput.c_str());
}
```

[c_str() is what you want.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Answer (score 0):

ifstream is using explicit constructor

```
explicit ifstream (const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in)
```

So you need to use strings' `const char* c_str() const` function to pass parameter.